# UIPopoverController with UIVisualEffectView over UISplitViewController - background is not getting blurred on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, iphone-6-plus

I am trying to display a popover controller over UISplitViewController.

The popover is displayed correctly. However, the visual effect view, which I have added to it, is not being displayed correctly on iPhone 6 plus (the background is not getting blurred). Here is the result which I am getting:

[image]

I have no clue how to resolve this issue.

The most similar question I was able to find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424165/how-to-implement-uivisualeffectview-in-uitableview-with-adaptive-segues). However, none of the solutions worked for me.

I have also tried modifying the presentation styles but it does not help as well. Setting the background for popover to `clearColor` also doesn't help...

I have uploaded a project to GitHub which you can find [here](https://github.com/AndriyGo/popoverProblem).

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Did you find your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behaviour, if you want to blur the background while the `popup` is presented, you should use `UIPresentationController` and it's delegates.

You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPresentationController_class/) and a top notch tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/96062/custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions-swift).

[Here](http://zappdesigntemplates.com/custom-presentations-using-uipresentationcontroller-swift/) you will find an example of what you're trying to achieve.