# CollectionView sizeForItemAtIndexPath never called

Tags: ios

This is driving me crazy! I have a `UICollectionViewController` as shown below:

```
class PhrasesCompactCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController
```

The `numberOfSections` and `cellForItemAt` are being called but the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` is never called. I am using the same exact code somewhere else and it fires correctly. I am using Xcode 8 Beta 6.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:  NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 120, height:120) 
}
```

Answer (score 281):

You need to specify that you implement the protocol `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in your class declaration.

`class PhrasesCompactCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Comment: I did this but it's still not called. :(

Comment: Annoying how I don't get an error while trying to use sizeForItemAt without the flow layout delegate. Just wasted 2 hours debugging :/

Answer (score 77):

I had the same problem. The one thing that helped me was to make the 'Estimated Size' for the Cell Size under the collectionView size inspector 'None'.

[image]

Comment: Somehow all other answers on all other posts about using `sizeForItemAt` failed to mention this. Very useful.

Comment: This is crazy!!!! I tested on iPhone 5 simulator with 10.3.1 iOS version and the method get called. on iPhone 5s simulator with 10.3.1 version method does not get called!!! I changed Estimate Size to None. It started to get called on iPhone 5s. WT WT WT

Comment: Thanks a lot! My collection view with custom `sizeForItemAt` worked well until Xcode 11.4 when suddenly the cells were wrong width. Tried bunch of things and this finally worked.

Comment: Thanks! It's both frustrating and infuriating that Apple made little things like this extremely complicated, and we all have to discuss about it here.

Comment: How do you set that without storyboards?

Answer (score 66):

In **Swift 3+** Use this method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width:(collectionView.frame.height-90)/2, height: 100)
}
```

If You are using UICollectionView then make sure that your class complies both Delegate

- **UICollectionViewDelegate**
- **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**

Comment: It is redundant to comply to `UICollectionViewDelegate` as UICollectionViewController already does.

Comment: @VanDuTran It's not redundant to state that it's required because being a UICollectionViewController isn't required...

Comment: I think you meant that a non collection view, Viewcontroller can be the UICollectionViewDelegate.

Comment: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout inherit from UICollectionViewDelegate so just implement the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Answer (score 35):

**Swift 5**

All these steps are **required** :

1. Conform to ***UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout***  <== Absolutely needed !!
2. and to `UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource`
3. Set these in viewDidLoad : `collectionView.delegate = self` and `collectionView.dataSource = self`
4. Set **Estimate Size to None** in the Interface Builder
5. Make sure the following method has **sizeForItemAt** and not **sizeForItemAtIndexPath**

as :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: 100, height:100)
}
```

Comment: Estimate Size to None - save my day!

Comment: How do you set `Estimate size to None` programmatically if you're not using IB?

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 3**

To set Cell Size of UICollectionView, you need to create and customise object of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Customise the properties and set that layout object to the UICollectionView object.

Change cellheight and cell cellWidth objects according to your requirement (the cell hight and width you want).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let cellWidth : CGFloat = myCollectionView.frame.size.width / 4.0
    let cellheight : CGFloat = myCollectionView.frame.size.height - 2.0
    let cellSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth , height:cellheight)

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical //.horizontal
    layout.itemSize = cellSize
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0
    myCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)

    myCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

**Make Sure: if you added sizeForItemAt indexPath method then must REMOVE  the method...**

> Remove Below Method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

}
```

Comment: How is this helpful?

Comment: Almas, This will helpful for set custom cell size of  UICollectionViewCell... There are variables cellWidth and cellHeight, in that you can define your own values... As well as "layout.sectionInset", "layout.minimumLineSpacing" and "layout.minimumInteritemSpacing", these variables also matters for UICollectionViewCell size..

Comment: This only works if all cells are the same size. The below answer is the correct answer

Comment: this is for changing size of the UICollectionView but not the cell inside the view

Comment: This is not an answer to why the delegate method is not called

Answer (score 13):

First class need to confirm to **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**. Then you need to write following code in **viewDidLoad()**:

//To tell the **UICollectionView** to use your **UIViewController's** **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** methods

```
collectionView.delegate = self
```

// If you want to set your own collection view flow layout

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical //depending upon direction of collection view

self.collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
```

By using this code **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

will get called, you can set size in this method.

Answer (score 8):

Three things you need to check if no answer works:

1. Implement FlowLayout Delegate : `class MyController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`
2. Use method for size of item for swift 3.0+: `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width / 3) - 1, height: collectionView.frame.width)
   }`
3. Select `Estimate size = None` in Inspect element of UICollectionView.

Comment: How do you set `Estimate size to None` programmatically if you're not using IB?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you put this in viewDidLoad()

```
collectionView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and nothing would fix it. I had a yellow warning saying to make it private because it came close to another function defined by the Layout Delegate. What fixed it for me was:

```html
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Notice the difference from "sizeForItemAtIndexPath" to the correct "sizeForItemAt".

I tore my hair out for days trying to figure this out and it finally worked. Below I will include all of my function to show you how I also "hid" a cell by making the height equal to 0.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let findIndex = labelArray.index(of: "\(labelArray[indexPath.row])")
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width

    if (findIndex! % 2 == 0){
        // Even index, show cell
        return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: 246)
    }
    else {
        return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
class YourClass: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {}
```

Answer (score 0):

may you set the wrong layout: `UICollectionViewLayout`, actually this layout should be `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` this like

Answer (score -1):

Use this method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

}
```

Instead of

```
private func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. Set the spacings in `xib/storyboard` and resize the cell with below-updated function for newer Swift versions. Happy coding !!

```
@objc(collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let numberOfItemsPerRow:CGFloat = 5
    
    if let collection = self.collectionView {
        let width = collection.bounds.width / numberOfItemsPerRow
        
        return CGSize(width: width, height: 36)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix the same issue by calling

```
collectionView.delegate = self
```

**BEFORE**

```
collectionView.dataSource = self
```

I have static items and never reload the data.
Apparently setting the dataSource triggers the loading of the collection data synchronously, so if the delegate is not set at this point, then `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` never gets called (unless `reloadData` is called later).

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue last night.  Finally solved it at midnight when I realised 'didSelectItemAtIndex' method was not closed off with a closure bracket "}"

I added a closure bracket at the very bottom of the class when asked by the compile error. So in effect all the methods below 'didSelectItemAtIndex' were inside that method.

Posting here just in case anyone else wastes 4 hours of their evenings on this one :-(

Answer (score -14):

For me (in Swift 3.1) the method must be declared public like this:

```
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       return CGSize()
    }
```

Don't forget to make it **public**.

Comment: `public` is what you use to make your code accessible between frameworks and modules.