# Blur effect on tableview background does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I'm trying to replicate the frosted glass look in the tableview at the bottom.

[image]

I tried the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25676264/1077789) and [here](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/152-uitableview-uitableviewcell-b-sides) but none of them seems to work now. Because this is the result I get.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
tableView.backgroundView = blurView
```

I tested on both a simulator and a device running iOS 12.1 but the issue is present in both.

[Demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcqmlmel194ii7h/BlurTableView.zip?dl=0)

What am I missing here?

Comment: You mean you want the same blur effect in your UITableviewCell?

Comment: set cell.backgroundColor = .clear

Comment: @NikunjRajyaguru No, just the background view of the table view. I got it fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work, because the `surfaceView` of your FloatingPanelController isn't transparent. Do this, when creating the floating panel:

```
floatingPanelController.surfaceView.backgroundColor = .clear
```